# Synchronization between several glDispatchCompute with same SSBOs

Tags: opengl, gpgpu

Let's say I have one compute shader A which writes to an SSBO, and then a second compute shader B which reads from the same SSBO.

Do I need to do anything special to ensure that A has finished executing before B starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, otherwise B may read data A is currently writing to or hasn't even reached yet. It's simple however, just call `glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)` between both invocations.

You should basically always use a memory barrier after a compute shader dispatch if you plan on reading data the compute shader has written to. There are a number of possible flags for different types of memory, but those can be easily found in the spec for `glMemoryBarrier`. Their names are pretty self-explainatory.

Comment: Will the barrier cause the calling thread to block until the previous compute shader execution is finished? Or will it just affect the future asynchronous scheduling of the shaders?

Comment: @avl_sweden: It depends on which barrier bits you specify. The bits define what operations want to *read* the data previously written. So if the bits don't specify a CPU-based reading operation, then they need not stall the CPU.

Comment: A follow up question: Isn't it wasteful to have following operations wait for ALL buffers? What If I have multiple SSBO's, and a compute shader only needs to see an up-to-date version of one of them? glMemoryBarrier is all SSBO's or none, right? I can't select only a few?

Comment: I did not have this case myself tbh, I think in reality it is also pretty uncommon to write something to a ssbo and not wanting to then read from this in the next invocation, but you could always split up computations into different shaders (or even invocations) and only sync on those you immediaty need. The other invocations would then need to happen after this sync so they can happen async to subsequent calls. Please keep in mind that's only what I believe to be working, you should profile to ensure you really gain something from such complication.